# Visual Studio adding OvalShape and RectangleShape tool references to a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Trying to add a 'box' to a form at design time, I looked up the msdn and it clearly states that I should be able to do this using the OvalShape and RectangleShape control tools in my Visual Studio 2008.

[shape container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488183.aspx)

Now it should be found under the visual Basic PowerPacks, but all I have listed is Pointer and PrintForm, how do I add it?

Comment: Why would the is belong on superuser? It's a question about Visual Studio!

Comment: You can close it now, thanks John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to add a DLL reference to your project...

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on that a bit? Thanks.

Comment: Right click on your project and select "Add Reference..."

Now, on my system the VB powerpacks are already installed, so you will probably have to explore to find the appropriate DLL, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Powerpacks.Vs.

Once thats done the controls should be visible...

Comment: Ah thanks.  It was actually an additional download, seems like I didn't have the latest version 3.0.  Anyway, I do now and it was nice and easy to set up.

The fact that you have to download it is actually on one of the other pages in the msdn.

Thanks for you help.