# C# How to drag and drop dynamically created rectangles

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

In the `UserControl` I made it is possible to add `Rectangles` by clicking. Those rectangles are saved in a List. Now I want to make it possible for the User to move those `Rectangles` that are drawn.
First I tried to add the `MouseDown`, `MouseMove` and `MouseUp` event to the `Rectangle` but that doesn't work because Drawing Rectangle is a Struct and not a control. I already did a Testproject and accomplished to move a button I put in in the UserControl by Designer. I tried with the code I got from [Drag and Drop Function with Drawing Rectangle C# .net - Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307938/drag-and-drop-function-with-drawing-rectangle-c-sharp-net-forms) but this example isn't about Rectangles. It is about Controls and I don't know how to use this idea for Rectangles because

```
rectangle.MouseDown += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  //do something
}
```

doesn't work. Any Ideas how to drag and drop Rectangles that are added dynamically?

Comment: You should add the MouseDown event to the UserControl. Then loop through the list and make a method to see if the coordinates are inside of a Rectangle. If it is, then hook and move it.

Comment: So you should add a `bool` value to, which is set to `true` inside the `MouseDown` event and set to `false` inside the `MouseUp` event. Then in the `MouseMove` event, check if the `mouseDown` value is `true`. If it is and a `Rectangle` was found, move it's position.

Comment: @kevintjuh93 thank you! I didn't thought about adding the MouseDown event to the UserControl. Now it works :) If you want you can comment the same as you wrote here in comments so I can mark this as the best answer.

Comment: Posted it, glad I could help. I had a grid with objects too and I also had to add a functionality to move them! If you have any other questions, let me know! @anastasia2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `MouseDown` event to the `UserControl`. Then loop through the list and make a method to see if the coordinates are inside of a `Rectangle`. If it is, then hook and move it.

So you should add a `bool` value to, which is set to `true` inside the `MouseDown` event and set to `false` inside the `MouseUp` event. Then in the `MouseMove` event, check if the `mouseDown` value is `true`. If it is and a `Rectangle` was found, move it's position.